# Append new line after match in multiple files with sed

Tags: bash, sed

I'm writing a script

One goal of the script is to append a new ***codeline*** after a match, with *foo*, in multiple `.yml` files recursively.

```
# Append new line after match in multiple files with sed
## sed -i -se "s/\foo/bar/g" *.yml
grep -rl foo * .| xargs sed -i -e "s/\foo/a bar/g" *.yml
```

I **expected** after every match with *foo*, because of `/a`, *bar* would be added on a new line in all `.yml` files.

I get **unexpected** Sed outpout:
`sed: can't read *.yml: No such file or directory`

Details:

1. OS: Debian GNU/Linux 10
2. sed --version: sed (GNU sed) 4.7

Comment: Why are you using `xargs` and also giving a filename argument to `sed`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're supplying the filename arguments with `xargs`. You shouldn't also use `*.yml` as an argument. The shell will expand that to the `.yml` files in the current directory, and you'll get an error if there aren't any.

If you want `grep -r` to only examine `.yml` files, use the `--include` option.

```
grep -rl --include='*.yml' foo . | xargs sed -i -e "s/foo/a bar/g"
```

Note that the `s` command isn't used for appending a new line after a line. It's used for substituting within the same line. `s/foo/ a bar/g` replaces all the `foo` on the line with `a bar`. If you want to append, get rid of the `s` command. Also, you don't put `/g` at the end of the `a` command.

```
grep -rl --include='*.yml' foo . | xargs sed -i -e "/foo/a bar"
```

See [How to insert text after a certain string in a file?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121161/how-to-insert-text-after-a-certain-string-in-a-file)

Comment: Hi, testing it now Output: `sed: -e expression #1, char 45: Invalid back reference`

Comment: That makes no sense. There's only about 12 characters in the expression, not 45.

Comment: You're not using the `a` command to append after a line. You have `s/foo/a bar/`, which means to replace `foo` with `a bar`.

Comment: It's probably because you had the extra `s` at the beginning, so the command wasn't being understood correctly.

Comment: Thnx the get rid of `s` did the trick. Somehow in `yml` file  `bar/g` is included

Comment: bar is as expected at new line but bar comes with `/g`

Comment: You don't need `/g` at the end, that's part of the substitute command, not the append command.

Comment: Thnx for the help @Barmar and quickly response. I didn't see any trees in de wood

Comment: I used `/g` for global uses, I intented that this was necessary to be recursively